# AngularJS: ignoring Content-Type parameter

Tags: javascript, rest, http-headers, angularjs

I am currently struggling with an error that appears in my Chrome developer tools console

```
GET http://localhost:8080/movie_db/search/movie?movieTitle=Machete 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
```

when I try to connect to my REST service with angular JS. Since I had this issue before when I tried to access the REST service via a Simple REST plugin in Chrome, I assume that most likely a missing Content-Type header parameter is the reason for that (should be Content-Type: 'application/json').

Angular JS website says, that one could set header parameters as follows: `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['My-Header']='value'`. Regretfully this didn't have any impact and the problem still exists.

Thus I'd like to know how I can manipulate the header parameters with angular JS that are sent over to my REST service.

Right at the moment, my code looks like this:

```
  function SearchMovieController($scope, $resource) {

  $scope.SearchMovie = $resource('http://localhost\\:8080/movie_db/search/:action',
            {action: 'movie', movieTitle: 'Machete'},
            {get: {method: 'JSONP', headers: [{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, {'Accept' : 'application/json'}]}});

        $scope.SearchMovie.get()
    }
```

Server side looks as follows (I use Spring MVC):

**CONTROLLER:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping( "/search/movie" )
public class SearchController { // TODO rename?

private final TheMovieDBService theMovieDBService;

@Autowired
public SearchController( TheMovieDBService theMovieDBService ) {
    this.theMovieDBService = theMovieDBService;
}


@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json" )
public Map<String, Object> search( @RequestParam String movieTitle ) {
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    try {
        TheMovieDBSearchResult searchResult =  theMovieDBService.searchMovie( movieTitle );
        response.put( "result", searchResult );
        response.put( "success", "true" );
    } catch ( EncoderException e ) {
        response.put( "success", "false" );
    }
    return response;
}
}
```

**web.xml**

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>json</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.u6f6o.apps.movie_db.config.web.ServletConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>json</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Since you're using JSONP I don't think content-type is relevant, unless the server is doing something weird. JSONP adds a `<script>` tag to the page rather than using AJAX.

Comment: Are you sure your REST service is set up correctly to give responses that work with JSONP?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MattB., I edited the origin post and added the controller code and content of web.xml on the server side

Comment: consumes="application/json" was the problem, now it works, thanks for pointing me to the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to step through all of Angular's $httpBackend stuff just recently, and JSONP uses a different method to load data than the other requests.

**EDIT: The code in question**

So if you specify jsonp has your method it is using the following method to load your data. This will, of course, completely ignore any headers you set yourself.

in $httpBackend:

```
function jsonpReq(url, done) {
    // we can't use jQuery/jqLite here because jQuery does crazy shit with script elements, e.g.:
    // - fetches local scripts via XHR and evals them
    // - adds and immediately removes script elements from the document
    var script = rawDocument.createElement('script'),
        doneWrapper = function() {
          rawDocument.body.removeChild(script);
          if (done) done();
        };

    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;

    if (msie) {
      script.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (/loaded|complete/.test(script.readyState)) doneWrapper();
      };
    } else {
      script.onload = script.onerror = doneWrapper;
    }

    rawDocument.body.appendChild(script);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, so there is no way to specifiy the header parameters when using jsonp?

Comment: For JSONP, you can only set headers on the server-side. The client-side will always assume that the `src` of the `<script>` tag points to a file of type `text/javascript` (unless you set a different `type` attribute, which would only be relevant if you were using VBScript or something). Remember, it's just like any other `<script>` tag except it's being loaded after the initial page load.